# C# Convert html time to hours and minutes

Tags: c#, time, web-scraping, duration

How do I convert from a string of this format:

```
PTDHMS
```

for example:

```
<time datetime="PT15H10M">
```

(That I get from parsing the duration of a movie from imdb) To a readable formatt like HH:MM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
TimeSpan t = System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan("PT15H10M");
```